# joint_state_publisher doesn't fully update source_list with use_gui=true

Tags: ros, joint-state-publisher, ros-kinetic, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to implement my own IK algorithm, so I add a source into the source_list parameter of joint_state_publisher node in the following test.launch file, in my hexapod package:

```
<launch>
<arg name="model" default="$(find hexapod)/urdf/hexapod2.xacro"/>
<arg name="gui" default="true"/>

<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(arg model)" />

<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" >
    <rosparam param="source_list">["ik_joint_states"]</rosparam>
    <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
</node>

</launch>
```

and

```
roslaunch hexapod test.launch
```

When I am done IK calculation, I want to publish the joint positions to topic "/ik_joint_states" and I expect joint_state_publisher will update.
After the launch file is launched, in a second terminal I typed the command to monitor all joint positions of my robot (they are initially all zeros):

```
rostopic echo /joint_states
```

in a third terminal I publish faked joint positions to topic "/ik_joint_states", pretending I have calculated these joint positions:

```
rostopic pub -1 /ik_joint_states sensor_msgs/JointState "header:
seq: 0
stamp: {secs: 0, nsecs: 0}
frame_id: ''
name: ['leftFrontLeg_J01', 'leftFrontLeg_J12', 'leftFrontLeg_J23']
position: [1, 2, 3]
velocity: [] 
effort: []"
```

Strange thing happend, only one joint position got updated, as I can see from the second terminal. If I enter the above command again, another joint position got updated, so I will have to enter the command 3 times to get all 3 joint positions updated.

Then I read the source code of [joint_state_publisher](https://github.com/ros/joint_state_publisher/blob/kinetic-devel/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher), I don't see any bug with the none-GUI part, so I relaunch the launch file with gui:=false

```
roslaunch hexapod test.launch gui:=false
```

and now the problem is gone, I enter the command once to get all 3 joint positions updated, which is what I expected.
Is there a bug in joint_state_publisher with gui on? or have I done something wrong?

I am using ros kinetic on ubuntu 16.04.5

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304585/joint_state_publisher-doesn%27t-fully-update-source_list-with-use_gui=true/) by [hyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37855/hyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-10-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

At first I thought your issue was due to the lack of zeros at `velocity` and `effort` message fields for each joint. I tested adding them to the message, but the issue was still there, exactly as you explained.

My best guess is that `joint_state_publisher` was developed expecting you to choose one (and only) input source for your angles. The [package documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher) suggests (but does not confirm) it:

```
There are four possible sources for the value of each JointState:  
 1. Values directly input through the GUI
 2. JointState messages that the node subscribes to 
 3. The value of another joint
 4. The default value
```

It makes sense after all. Unless the sliders from the GUI autoupdate their values, there would be two different set of values competing against each other:

- the one from the topic described in
  `source_list`;
- and the one from the GUI.

Which one should the joints assume in dispute cases? Maybe the simple assumption was best suited at the time.

P.S.: The issue you described was marked as a bug in this [Github issue](https://github.com/ros/joint_state_publisher/issues/4).

---

Originally posted by [Bruno Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/37834/bruno-lima/) with karma: 81 on 2018-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37855/hyan/) on 2018-10-01**:
Thank you!